# Errores Logcat y compilacion de klotin

Tags: packages, find, jetpack-compose, logcat

Estoy haciendo una delivery app con Kotlin teniendo ayuda de daggerhilt para las inyecciones sin embargo todo compila correctamente y gradle sincroniza muy bien y no marca ningun error de compilación pero al momento de ejecutarse la app se cierra automáticamente y en el log cat  me marca estos errores alguien sabe que puede ser ?

> studio.deploy pid-3583 Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package:Pcdemo1
> studio.deploy pid-3583 Could not find apks for this package:Pcdemo1
> studio.deploy pid-3583 Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package:Pcdemo1
> studio.deploy pid-3583 Could not find apks for this package:Pcdemo1

Si alguien sabe la respuesta me ayudaría mucho.